# Why does Google Analytics Query Data only go back 4 months?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, if go to Acquisition->SEO-Queries, and I make the data range a full year, I only get data for 5 months. Before that there is no data.

Why?

Can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for SEO queries is provided by Google through a connection with Search Console (formerly Web Master Tools). Google only stores the last 90 days of data. 
There is no direct way to restore data more than 90 days old.

Comment: However, I would note that certain solutions like Supermetrics can.